# Is there a Evernote save/clip button for html?

Tags: html, evernote

I would like to add social media buttons and productivity buttons to my blog.
Ex: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Is there an official Evernote button that would trigger "save to evernote" or something similar? or any other resource that is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I know of would be using AddToAny:

- Go to the [form for getting buttons for websites](http://www.addtoany.com/buttons/for/website) .
- Select more options next to the Get Button Code button
- Select prioritize services and then Evernote from the list.
- Embed the button code on your blog!

Answer (score 1):

Found the url code for Evernote Clipping, as below.

Just in case if only need the Evernote one not others.

```
 <li>
    <a href="http://www.evernote.com/clip.action?url={{your-site-url}}" target="_blank" title="Clip to Evernote" onclick="window.open('http://www.evernote.com/clip.action?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&amp;t=' +  encodeURIComponent(document.title)); return false;">
    <img src="{{your-icon-url}}">
    </a>
    </li>
```